# class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$SerializableNoOp cannot be cast to class org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Dispatcher

Tags: java, spring

After upgrading from Spring 5.3.21 to 6.0.13 and updating java 12 to 17, we're getting errors on all our services like this one below. I could not find any other posts around the internet pointing in any direction. We include / pull in dependencies (xxx-3.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar) from other repositories. Those are build using the same maven parent, so versions all are the same.

Not sure what more I can include. Just some suggestions on how to further investigate would be great. I'm really stuck atm and don't know a way forward.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxController' defined in file [xxx/xxxController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'xxxService' defined in file [xxx/xxxService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'networkingService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at a.b.c.shared.BaseService.run(BaseService.java:106) ~[classes/:na]
    at a.b.c.ConfigService.main(ConfigService.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxService' defined in file [xxx/xxxService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'networkingService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:498) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.buildProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:228) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:155) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.buildLazyResolutionProxy(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.buildLazyResolutionProxy(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.getLazyResolutionProxyIfNecessary(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:867) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:828) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$SerializableNoOp cannot be cast to class org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Dispatcher (org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$SerializableNoOp and org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Dispatcher are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at a.b.c.commons.commit.service.CommitService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.setCallbacks(<generated>) ~[xxx-3.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:91) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.buildProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
```

I tried to find out what version of Spring could cause this. Did a complete clean of the environment (rm ~/.m2/repository and target). I also tried to create a new minimal service from scratch, but ran into the same issue once I include the dependencies.